# How to make one executable visual studio, that users can run?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I make an executable on visual studio I run into the same problems:

1. There are multiple files that the user needs to run the program (not just 1). Even if I go into the publish settings and select to produce a single executable, usually it will still include more than one file sometimes and I don't know why.
2. Windows will usually detect the program as a virus, EVEN if I make the program myself and there's nothing suspicious in the code. I can make ANY program that does ANYTHING and by default it will be flagged as a virus. How do I make it stop?
3. Finally, sometimes even if I elect to produce one executable file, the user cannot run it if they do not have .net installed. How do I configure the settings so that the user can run the file without .NET?

In summary, I want to just make one executable file that is not flagged as a virus and the user doesn't need to install .NET (or anything) to run it, other than ONE executable file.

This is specifically in regards to Visual Studio because I can use other IDEs and I don't get these issues. Any VS, 2019, 2022, etc.

Comment: Note that this is a **question** and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural - it's not a *list of questions* site. Check the [help] for more about that topic. Normally, unless you include non-standard assemblies, C# generates .exe files that can be distributed alone. Most C# programs do not cause virus issues. Without seeing your code, who knows why yours does? And finally, every Windows computer has .NET installed on it, so there should be no reason for the user to need to run without it. If you're not developing for .NET, don't use C#.

Comment: This may help get you going in the right direction... [Single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli)

Comment: Also, on the topic of the virus warning issue you're having - maybe your computer is infected with a virus, and it's infecting the applications you create.

Comment: _This is specifically in regards to Visual Studio because I can use other IDEs and I don't get these issues_: If this is the case, you may consider using of the other IDEs that don't result in the issue. If one gets his/her/their feet wet every time he/she/they walk in water, and one doesn't like getting his/her/their feet wet, then he/she/they should consider not walking in the water.

Comment: You may consider performing more research to learn about _.NET Framework, .NET Core, and .NET_.  Here's a good place to start: [What is .NET Framework?](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet-framework). Creating an installer for your app and installing it, may help with your anti-virus issue. Of course that is as long as you haven't actually written a virus.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might want to learn about [Single-file Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview) and [Self-contained Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained). The virus issue sounds like an overactive antivirus, so I'd change the settings to exclude your project directory.